# How to write a Elastic Aggregation on multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having a requirement to aggregate the Elastic Search on multiple fields.

I have a nested field called Working days and below is the mapping for the same.

```
"workingDays": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "mon": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "availability": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                           "type": "keyword"
                         }
                    }
                },
                "notes": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        },
        "tue": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "availability": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                           "type": "keyword"
                         }
                    }
                },
                "notes": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, the mapping goes on for all the days.

Now, the data is shown as below

```
"workingdays": {
        "mon": {
            "availability": true,
            "title": "Monday",
            "notes": ""
        },
        "tue": {
            "title": "Tuesday",
            "notes": "On Tuesdays, drop off and pick up times must be scheduled between 12pm to 2pm",
            "availability": false
        }
    }
```

So, my requirement is as follows. I need to aggregate and result in all the data which are available on specific days, something similar to this.

```
"buckets": [
   {
      "key": "Monday",
      "doc_count": 3
   },
   {
      "key": "Tuesday",
      "doc_count": 5
   }
]
```

I have tried nested aggregation, composition aggregation, and multi-field aggregation but none of them resulted in a usable format.

Comment: Since your working days are not arrays but a simple multi-level object, I'm curious why did you decide to make all those fields `nested`? it doesn't really make sense

Comment: I have the option to remove them from `nested`, if I remove it is there a way to get the result?

Comment: Can you also share the query you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nested aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) inside of [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) inside of nested aggregation :).

```
PUT test_days
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "workingdays": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "mon": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "availability": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              "notes": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          "tue": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "availability": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              "notes": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
POST test_days/_doc?refresh
{
  "workingdays": {
    "mon": {
      "availability": true,
      "title": "Monday",
      "notes": ""
    },
    "tue": {
      "title": "Tuesday",
      "notes": "On Tuesdays, drop off and pick up times must be scheduled between 12pm to 2pm",
      "availability": false
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
GET test_days/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "total": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "workingdays"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "monday": {
          "filters": {
            "filters": {
              "monday_availability": {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "workingdays.mon",
                  "query": {
                    "term": {
                      "workingdays.mon.availability": {
                        "value": true
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "tuesday_availability": {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "workingdays.tue",
                  "query": {
                    "term": {
                      "workingdays.tue.availability": {
                        "value": true
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: case sensitive!! double check if you are using `workingDays` or `workingdays`.

[image]